# LINQ in foreach Head

Tags: c#, linq

Short question
When I use a Linq query in a foreach header, this is then built over and over again.
Or is it better to make the list first and then go through it?
For example:

```
  List<WashObjectReservationModel> reservations = washObjManager.GetReservations(currentProductionType);

                    if (reservations.Any(x => washObject.PreparationJob.PartTypes.Select(y => y.Number).Contains(x.PartType.Type)))
                    {
                        bool validForProduction = true;
                        foreach (var partType in washObject.PreparationJob.PartTypes.Where(x => reservations.Select(y => y.PartType.Type).Contains(x.Number)))
                        {
                            StoragePositionResult typePos = storageManager.GetPosition(partType.Number, StorageType.Cleaned, washObject.PreparationJob.CreateDate);

                            validForProduction = typePos.WashObject == null;

                            if (validForProduction)
                            {
                                logger.Info($"WashObject \"{washObject.Number}\" is required at production with PartType {partType.Number}");

                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] complete with sample data so that we can better understand the context of your problem, especially the _types_ involved.

Comment: Try to read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888940/using-linq-in-foreach-loop-declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably worried because, in classic `for` loop, the terminating condition **is** evaluated at every iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someExpensiveComputation(); i++) ...
```

This is not the case in `foreach` loops: The expression is evaluated **once** to create an enumerator over your LINQ query, which is then iterated through.